# How to print in PrintNode.js using axios? example code

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, axios, zpl

So after searching for a long time I wanna share my code. This code is meant to silent print ZPL(zebra printer) labels from a browser using Javascript or Node.js.

First install axios using NPM.

Then copy this code

```
const axios = require("axios");
var dataprint = "DATA HERE!!!";

async function makeGetRequest() {
    let payload = {
        printerId: "Printer ID(login in Printnode here you can find the id of your printer)",
        title: "test print job",
        contentType: "raw_base64",
        content: dataprint,
        source: "pack",
    };

    let res = await axios.post(
        "https://api.printnode.com/printjobs",
        payload,
        {
            auth: {
                username: "API key. Find it on printnode website",
                password: "",
            },
        }
    );

    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
}

makeGetRequest();
```

Hope I can help some people with this code! Let me know in the comments

Comment: But that's just a standard HTTP POST request with Axios... What problem exactly did you solve? What's special about this solution? Also, if you want to share something and post the solution you came up with, that's a good thing and you are welcome to do so; but you are supposed to ask a question as you normally would, then answer it yourself.

Comment: Good question. The problem it solved is silent Raw printing from a web application. This solution is for Zebra printer which have their own language.  People who would like to use PrintNode because of their requirements have an easy way now to just copy this code and try it out.  I just wanna make the world of programming a little better whenever I have the possibility to make coding easier for people like me. Who just start coding.